How to debounce each iteration in the loop
I'm using lodash debounce function. My problem is that I don't know how to properly use debounce within for of loop so it debounces every iteration separately, not all loop at once.
Here is code of debouncing I did:
const debouncedFetchData = useCallback(
    debounce(async (id) => {
      const anime = await fetchAnimeData(id);
      setAnimeData(prevData => [...prevData, anime]);
    }, 1000), 
    []
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataForRecommendations = async () => {
      if (recommendations) {
        for (const item of recommendations) {
          debouncedFetchData(item.entry.mal_id);
        }
      }
    };
  
    fetchDataForRecommendations();
    setAnimeData([]); 
  }, [recommendations]);

Here is the full code of the component:
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useGetAnimeRecommendationsQuery } from '../../api/apiSlice';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

import fetchAnimeData from '../../utils/fetchAnimeData';
import AnimeCard from '../animeCard/AnimeCard';
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner';
import ErrorMessage from '../errorMessage/ErrorMessage';

import './animeRecommendations.scss';

const AnimeRecommendations = ({id}) => {
  const {
    data: animeRecommendations = {},
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error
  } = useGetAnimeRecommendationsQuery(id);
  const [animeData, setAnimeData] = useState([]);
  const animeRecommendationsData = animeRecommendations.data;

  const recommendations = useMemo(() => {
    if (!animeRecommendations || !animeRecommendationsData || !animeRecommendationsData.length) {
      return [];
    }
    if (animeRecommendationsData.length < 10) {
      return animeRecommendationsData;
    }

    const recommendations = animeRecommendationsData.slice();
    return recommendations.slice(0, 10);
  }, [animeRecommendationsData]);
  
  const debouncedFetchData = useCallback(
    debounce(async (id) => {
      const anime = await fetchAnimeData(id);
      setAnimeData(prevData => [...prevData, anime]);
    }, 1000), 
    []
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataForRecommendations = async () => {
      if (recommendations) {
        for (const item of recommendations) {
          debouncedFetchData(item.entry.mal_id);
        }
      }
    };
  
    fetchDataForRecommendations();
    setAnimeData([]); 
  }, [recommendations]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Spinner />
  } else if (isError) {
    return <ErrorMessage errorStatus={error.status} />
  } 

  const renderAnimeRecommendations = (arr) => {
    console.log(arr);
    return arr.map((item, i) => {
      if (item && item.data) {
        const { mal_id } = item.data;

        return ( 
          <AnimeCard 
            key={mal_id}
            id={mal_id}
            data={item.data}
          />
        )
      } else {
        return <ErrorMessage key={i} errorStatus={429} />
      }
    })
  }

  const items = renderAnimeRecommendations(animeData);
  return (
    <div className="recommendations">
    {!recommendations.length ? 
      <div className='title title_fz16fw300' style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        There is no recommendations for this anime
      </div> :
      <div className="recommendations__wrapper">
        {items}
      </div>}
    </div> 
  )
}

export default AnimeRecommendations;

Currently animeData contains an array with one object, but it should contain an array of 10 objects. I tried different approaches, but none of them worked. Also tried to ask chatGPT but it didn't help either.

What are you exactly trying to achieve with the debounce call? Debouncing is mainly used to avoid sending requests too often, e.g. after multiple user interactions like clicks on some button. From what you describe, I think you might not need any debouncing at all.

@Rico fetchAnimeData send request to the api. In the for of loop I am calling this function and it makes all 10 requests in a short period of time which causes rate limiting error from api. I want to debounce every iteration of the loop so It calls fetchAnimeData with a certain delay
